# Cron Job PHP Script Error

Tags: php, cron

I had made a cron job with this comment : "/home/username/public_html/cron.php"

My php (cron.php)

```
    <?php 

    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'name';
    $pass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'dbname';

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

    $sql = "Update table;";
    $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

and this is the error :

```
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 3: =: command not found
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 4: =: command not found
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 5: =: command not found
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 6: =: command not found
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/username/public_html/cron.php: line 8: `$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);'
```

Anyone can help in solving this? thank you.

Comment: The shell doesn't know how to interpret PHP code. Use the php interpreter and/or a shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is being interpreted as a shell script.  To run a PHP script at the command line:

```
php /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

Or add this to the top of the file and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

(or whatever is the path your PHP executable)